# Different session ID every time session_start is executed

Tags: php, session, sessionid

I have the following source code

session1.php

```
<?php

session_start();
echo session_id();

?>
```

session2.php

```
<?php

session_start();
echo session_id();

?>
```

when I access session1.php then access session2.php, I get a different ouput.

Why is this doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browser is not sending the session cookie back to the server. This can have two reasons.

1. The browser is configured not to send cookies to the server. You cannot force the browser to send cookies. In this case your only option is to pass the session identifier in the URL, although this is generally not a good idea.
2. The server is configured not to use cookies for the session identifier (by means of the [session.use_cookies](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-cookies) configuration option).

Comment: // just checked phpinfo().session.use_cookies is set to On, but session.save_path has no value. Is it possible that session.save_path is causing this issue?

Comment: @Moon It's certainly strange. In my phpinfo(), it is set even though it is not mentioned in php.ini explicitly.

Comment: I know this is old post, but was facing the same issue with IE only and found the solution, so want to share in case anybody faces the same issue.   I was un-setting all global variables in my php code and IE wasn't working

Answer (score 0):

If you're running under *nix, try setting `session.save_path` to `/tmp`. If that doesn't work, look in your browser's cookie cache to see if the cookie is indeed being saved by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try storing your session cookies in the database rather than on the server. This saved me heaps of time out and other session cookie problems especially if you are on a shared server.

This might help: http://www.raditha.com/php/session.php.

Good Luck

Comment: I think when you save the session keys then use something like memcache.

Answer (score 0):

A rare edge case, but I found that having a dot in the session name of `php.ini` caused this problem!!

```
session.name = THIS.DOESNTWORK
```